# Thread synchronization dont work unless add print statement

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I am making a program that checks if a string is contained in a tree of directories and text files and I use producer-consumer pattern. Unfortunately my consumer thread doesn't want to stop unless I add a print statement. I tried everything - synchronization, making fields volatile but still can't find the problem.

```
public class Producer
extends Thread
{
private volatile Storage store;
private volatile Reader read;

Producer(Storage store, Reader read){
    this.read = read;
    this.store = store;
}



public void run()
{
    while (!read.isEmpty()) {

            String FileName = read.returnAllPaths().peek().getFileName().toString();
            String item = null;
            try {
                item = read.returnAllPaths().take().toString();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            File currentFile = new File(item);
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(currentFile))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    FileAndLine current = new FileAndLine(FileName, line);
                    store.fillStore(current);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }

    store.setEndOfPaths(true);
}
}
public class Consumer
extends Thread
{
private volatile Storage store;
private String clue;

public Consumer(Storage store, String clue){
    this.store = store; 
    this.clue = clue;
}

public void run()
{

    FileAndLine currentLine;

    while(!store.isEndOfPaths() || !store.isEmpty()){
        currentLine = store.depleteStore();
        System.out.println("q");
        if(currentLine.line.contains(clue))
            System.out.println(currentLine.FileName + ": " + currentLine.line);
    }
}

}
public class Storage {
private BlockingQueue<FileAndLine> Store;
private boolean full;
private volatile boolean endOfPaths;


public Storage(){
    Store = new LinkedBlockingQueue<FileAndLine>();
    full = false;
}

private boolean isFull(){
    return full;
}

public synchronized BlockingQueue<FileAndLine> getStore(){
    return this.Store;
}

public synchronized boolean isEmpty(){
    return Store.isEmpty();
}


public synchronized void setEndOfPaths(boolean set){
    endOfPaths = set;
}

public synchronized boolean isEndOfPaths(){
    return endOfPaths;
}

public synchronized void fillStore(FileAndLine line){
    while(isFull()){
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Store.add(line);

    full = false;
    notifyAll();

    if(Store.size() == 1000){
        full = true;
    }
}

public synchronized FileAndLine depleteStore(){

    FileAndLine line;
    if(endOfPaths == true && Store.isEmpty())
    {
        return new FileAndLine("", "");
    }
    while(Store.isEmpty())
    {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    line = new FileAndLine(Store.remove());

    if(Store.size() < 1000){
        full = false;
        notifyAll();
    }
    return line;
}
```

}

Comment: You are testing `read.isEmpty()` and this needs to be thread safe.

Comment: I can't see what is the essential logic here but I suspect you could replace all this with one parallelStream.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
private volatile Reader read;
```

This means the `Reader read` *reference* is volatile.  This means when you read this field, it's access is volatile.  However, it doesn't mean the object referenced is thread safe.  The test you have is

```
while (!read.isEmpty()) {
```

and it is this test which has to be thread safe.

Note: when you write to the console, you are using a synchronized block indirectly as all the method of `PrintStream` is `synchronized` and this has both a read and write barrier.

> I am making a program that checks if a string is contained in a tree of directories and text files

```
String text = "looking-for";
Files.walk(Paths.get("mydir"))
        .parallel()
        .filter(p -> p.toFile().isFile())
        .forEach(p -> {
            try {
                if (Files.lines(p)
                        .anyMatch(l -> l.contains(text)) {
                    System.out.println("file " + p + " contains " + text);
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

You don't need manage all the handling of dividing up the work to multiple threads and co-ordinating them, esp when you have a task which is data processing.